# Is the following inequality holds true for all positive integers?

Tags: inequality

If $a , b , c$ and $d$ are positive integers, 
and $ab$ is greater than $cd$,
then,  is   $a+b$  greater than or equal to $c+d$, always true?

Comment: 5x5 > 24x1 so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at all.

Consider $a=b=3$ and $c=1,d=8$. Then $ab=9$ while $cd=8$ however $a+b=6$ while $c+d=9$.

If you want a trivial example, you can take $c=0$, any non zero $a,b$. Then take $d$ very large.

Answer (score 1):

Nope...consider:
$$100=20 \times 5$$ and $$54=27 \times 2$$